# Detect caps on bottles using opencv and python

Tags: opencv, object, colors, geometry, detection

I know that there are a hundred topics about my question in all over the web, but i would like to ask specific for my problem because I tried almost all solutions without any success.

I am trying to count circles in an image (yes i have already tried hough circles but due to light reflections, i think, on my object is not very robust).
Then I tried to create a classifier (no success i think there is no enough features so the detection is not good)

I have also tried HSV conversation and tried to find my object with color (again I had some problems because of the light and the variations of colors)
As you can see on image, there are 8 caps and i would like to be able to count them.

Using all of this methods, i was able to detect the objects on an image (because I was optimizing all the parameters of functions for the specific image) but as soon as I load a new, similar, image the results was disappointing.

Please follow this link to see the [Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5502709/frame71.jpg)

Bellow you can find parts of everything i have tried:

**1. Hough circles**

```
img = cv2.imread('frame71.jpg',1)

img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
if img == None:
    print "There is no image file. Quiting..."
    quit()

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,3,50,
                            param1=55,param2=125,minRadius=25,maxRadius=45)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

print len(circles[0,:])
cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**2. HSV Transform, color detection**

```
def image_process(frame, h_low, s_low, v_low, h_up, s_up, v_up, ksize):
  temp = ksize
  if(temp%2==1):
   ksize = temp
  else:
   ksize = temp+1
  #if(True):
  # return frame
  #thresh = frame
  #try:
  #TODO: optimize as much as possiblle this part of code
  try:
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   lower = np.array([h_low, s_low, v_low],np.uint8)
   upper = np.array([h_up,s_up,h_up],np.uint8)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv,hsv, mask= mask)
   thresh = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   #thresh = cv2.threshold(res, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
   thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
   thresh = cv2.medianBlur(thresh,ksize)
  except Exception as inst:
    print type(inst)
   #cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
  return thresh
```

**3. Cascade classifier**

```
img = cv2.imread('frame405.jpg', 1)
cap_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haar_30_17_16_stage.xml')
caps = cap_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
#print caps
for (x,y,w,h) in caps:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)


#cv2.rectangle(img, (10,10),(100,100),(0,255,255),4)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

quit()
```

About training the classifier I really used a lot of variations of images, samples, negatives and positives, number of stages, w and h but the results was not very accurate.

Finally I would like to know from your experience which is **the best method I should follow** and I will stick on that in order to optimize my detection. Keep in mind that all images are similiar but NOT identical. There are some differences due to light, movement etc

Than you in advance,

Comment: Do you have access to images or do you have access to a video feed? If it's a video, you should be able to segment the bottles by their motion, and then do further processing on the extracted region.

Comment: The flow of bottles is constant, but i take a picture exactly when there are below the cam.

Comment: Add the moment I tried find caps using color, and i think the problem is the transparent nylon above caps. I test my code with another image and i was able to hide everything else in the image except the color, but with caps as you can see in the image I cant do it. Ranges of HSV are set to maximums and minimums but yellow was excluded!

Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5502709/te.png

Comment: @user2117118 you found any solution to this problem. I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello finally i think I found a way to count caps on bottles.

1. Read image
2. Teach (find correct values for HSV up/low limits)
3. Select desire color (using HSV and mask)
4. Find contours on the masked image
5. Find the minCircles for contours
6. Reject all circles beyond thresholds

I have also order a polarized filter which I think it will reduce glares a lot. I am open to suggestions for further improvement (robustness and speed). Both robustness and speed is crucial for my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiment with the sample image. I'm posting my results, and if you find it useful, you can improve it further and optimize. Here are the steps:

- downsample the image
- perform morphological opening
- find Hough circles
- cluster the circles by radii (bottle circles should get the same label)
- filter the circles by a radius threshold
- you can also cluster circles by their center x and y coordinates (I haven't done this)
- prepare a mask from the filtered circles and extract the possible bottles region
- cluster this region by color

Code is in C++. I'm attaching my results.

```
    Mat im = imread(INPUT_FOLDER_PATH + string("frame71.jpg"));
    Mat small;
    int kernelSize = 9; // try with different kernel sizes. 5 onwards gives good results 

    pyrDown(im, small); // downsample the image

    Mat morph;
    Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(kernelSize, kernelSize));
    morphologyEx(small, morph, MORPH_OPEN, kernel); // open
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(morph, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray.rows/8.0);   // find circles

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    // cluster the circles by radii. similarly you can cluster them by center x and y for further filtering
    Mat circ = Mat(circles);
    Mat data[3];
    split(circ, data);

    Mat labels, centers;
    kmeans(data[2], 2, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 2, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    Mat rgb;
    small.copyTo(rgb);
    //cvtColor(gray, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(Size(gray.cols, gray.rows), CV_8U);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);

        float r = centers.at<float>(labels.at<int>(i));
        if (r > 30.0f && r < 45.0f) // filter circles by radius (values are based on the sample image)
        {   
            // just for display
            circle(rgb, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0);
            circle(rgb, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0);
            // prepare a mask
            circle(mask, center, radius, Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0);
        }
    }

    // use each filtered circle as a mask and extract the region from original downsampled image
    Mat rgb2;
    small.copyTo(rgb2, mask);

    // cluster the masked region by color
    Mat rgb32fc3, lbl;
    rgb2.convertTo(rgb32fc3, CV_32FC3);
    int imsize[] = {rgb32fc3.rows, rgb32fc3.cols};
    Mat color = rgb32fc3.reshape(1, rgb32fc3.rows*rgb32fc3.cols);
    kmeans(color, 4, lbl, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1.0), 2, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS);
    Mat lbl2d = lbl.reshape(1, 2, imsize);
    Mat lbldisp;
    lbl2d.convertTo(lbldisp, CV_8U, 50);
    Mat lblColor;
    applyColorMap(lbldisp, lblColor, COLORMAP_JET);
```

Results:

Filtered circles:

[image: Circles]

Masked:

[image: Masked]

Segmented:

[image: Segmented]

Comment: this is seemed promising, I will try to convert this and your ideas to my program, and i let you know!

Comment: please share python code of this answer.................